# PHP AJAX Dynamically Remove Data

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I am trying to use AJAX to dynamically delete a record from the database through the front end site, I have the code but when I click the delete button nothing happens, there is connection to the database I just cannot find the mistake in the code, all the code files are linked to one another.

The table I want to delete a record from is called recipes.

HTML

```
<div id="recipecards2" class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div id="recipecards" class="card">    
<div class="card-body">
<p>
<button type="button" id="deletebutton" class="btn btn-outline-danger" input type="submit" name="recipe_delete" data-id="<?php echo $recipe['recipe_id']; ?>">
<i style=color:black; class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete Recipe </button> </a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

Ajax PHP code

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/db.php');

if($_POST['itemid']){
    $query = "DELETE FROM recipes WHERE itemid= $recipe_data['recipe_id'];";
    $result = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(':itemid', $_POST['itemid']);
    $result->execute();

    echo $_POST['itemid'];
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#recipecards2').on('click', '#deletebutton', function() {
    // var that = this;
    var itemid = $('#recipecards').attr('data-id');

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/removeItemsFromList.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { itemid : itemid}
    });

    // If we're successfull!
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#recipecards2 > #recipecards[data-id="'+response+'"] ').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: You are passing a value to your query *and* preparing? That's just wrong. You are using named parameters wrong.

Comment: $query doesn't look right. Shoudln't there be :itemid so you can bind this later on?

Comment: @Script47 It it blank when I click the delete button

Comment: If you are going to use `data-*` attributes, you might as well use the `.data()` function too rather than the `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, your issue is that you are using [named parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) incorrectly, you are `prepare`ing your query, yet at the same time you are passing a value directly to it.

Change,

```
$query = "DELETE FROM recipes WHERE itemid= $recipe_data['recipe_id'];";
```

To,

```
$query = "DELETE FROM recipes WHERE itemid = :itemid;";
```

**Secondly**, if you are using the [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) properties, consider using the respective [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function too.

**Thirdly**, when you do an AJAX request and it doesn't go right, open your browser console and check the response of that request. That generally should point you in to the right direction.

**Fourthly**, your HTML for your button is malformed, take a look at your button code,

```
<button type="button" id="deletebutton" class="btn btn-outline-danger" input type="submit" name="recipe_delete" data-id="<?php echo $recipe['recipe_id']; ?>">
```

Notice how you have a `button`/`input` mix? Pick one, you don't need to have both.

Comment: Hey, @Script47, I tried the changing the query and the problem still persists, when I click the delete button nothing happens, I opened the google chrome console, went to network and saw the php file had no data in it.?

Comment: hey, I just removed input and kept button within the html code , same issue persists.

Comment: @HasnaatKhan you can't just remove it. Ensure that it doesn't have any dependencies in your code. Keep checking the console.

Comment: Yeah, the console keeps spitting out results for the remove ajax file :(

@Script47